# Java executing static imports

Tags: java, import, static

Following the this code of block of the image what is the expecting result
on the rabbit class I'm confused if the way the Hole class is instantiated is valid I'm assuming it is so the output will be

Here is the image with the code:
[image: Here is the image with the code]

- "dig'
- "dig"
- 9

Comment: Please show code as *text* rather than as images.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear to me what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The expected output would be

```
dig dig 9
```

The first call:

```
Hole.dig()
```

is a standard static method call which I assume doesn't surprise you.

The second call:

```
new Hole().dig()
```

is pretty bad code. (fine for when you are learning but not so great in the workplace). Your editor likely is warning you about this. This is calling the static dig() method but based on the declared/implied type of new Hole();

It is bad code because it will give you the idea that the instance has something to say about which method is being called.

for instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A().printMe();
    new C().printMe();

    A whichOne = new C();
    whichOne.printMe();
}

public static class A {
    public static void printMe() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
public static class C extends A {
    public static void printMe() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

this will print A , not C as you might expect. You are creating a C object but after you put it into an A variable, the static method will use the class of the containing variable to decide which method to call.

```
new C().printMe();
A whichOne = new C();
whichOne.printMe();
// gives C , A
```

This is confusing and generally frowned upon.

Lastly the static import:

```
import static hole.Hole.*; // import all static methods and variables from hole.Hole into here.
```

it pulls in Depth and any other methods (including dig, so just calling this would work as well:

```
dig();
```

When the Hole class is loaded it first sets Depth to 3. But even before the constructor is called the static block sets Depth to 9. So that is why Depth would contain 9.